# Flutter project debug is stopping in my vivo phone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging, adb

I am facing a difficult problem now.
Right now I can't do a flutter debug on my real phone device.
I've tried everything possible, but I still get this error and can't debug.
However, the installed app works properly.
However, the biggest problem is that I cannot debug because the debug frame is ended.
Any solution to this?
Please help me... This is very important for me.

Error:

Launching lib\main.dart on vivo X20 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on vivo X20.

Comment: Did you try flutter clean command?

Comment: Yes. I tried flutter clean command. And I restarted my phone. But the result is same.

Comment: Are you on a macbook?

Comment: If you are on Mac, this might be because you don't have sudo access. I think the debugger needs to read iOS logs that require sudo access. You can perhaps fix the issue by adding admin rights to your account (system preferences > User&Groups > Allow user to administer this computer). Of course, this might not be possible for everyone